# for iterating through string explicitly

Tags: bash

I have a python programme that I need to run in this way

```
python myprog.py --tuple "(20,10,)"
```

I want to iterate through a few types of tuple and run my programme

```
$ for i in "(20,10)" "(40,100,2)" ; do echo $i ; done
(20,10)
(40,100,2)
```

However, my programme only takes string explcitly

```
python myprog.py --tuple (20,)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How could we iterate through quotes explicitly? Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the relevant portions of your code?

Comment: parser.add_argument('--tuple', help='tuple', default="(100,)", type=str)

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate through quotes"?

Comment: Where did you want to do this iteration... in python or bash? Do you want `for i in "(20,10)" "(40,100,2)" ; do python myprog.py --tuple  "$i" ; done`?

Comment: Seems like a bash question rather than a Python question.

Comment: On a sidenote: `(` doesn't create a tuple in python, `,` does. You don't have to pass in the `(`, especially if you know it's a tuple anyways. Try `ast.literal_eval("20,3")` and ast.literal_eval("20,") to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "problem" of bash, not python. `(` is a special character for bash and must be escaped:

```
python myprog.py --tuple \(20,\)
```

or provided as fixed strings:

```
python myprog.py --tuple '(20,)'
```